# Finding comparisons in Merge sort

Tags: python-3.x

Trying to find a way to count the number of comparisons in mergesort. I've tried to make a list (compar[0] = compar[0]+1) but that gave back 104000 comparisons. Below I tried to make a variable and then add 1 but I am getting fewer comparison counts than I expected. Not sure where I am going wrong with this or what I could try.

```
import numpy as np
import random

def mergesort_helper(arr):
    call = 0
    compar = 0
    call +=1 
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        compar += 1
        return arr, call, compar
    if len(arr) > 1:
        # Get middle of array
        mid = len(arr) // 2
        # Getting left side
        left = arr[:mid]
        #Getting right side
        right = arr[mid:]
        # Sorting the first half
        call += mergesort_helper(left)[1]
        # Sorting the second half
        call += mergesort_helper(right)[1]
        lfirst= 0
        rfirst = 0
        merge = 0
    while lfirst< len(left) and rfirst < len(right):
        compar += 1
        if left[lfirst] < right[rfirst]:
            arr[merge] = left[lfirst]
            merge += 1
            lfirst+= 1
            
        else:
            arr[merge] = right[rfirst]
            rfirst += 1
            merge += 1
    # Checking if any element was left
    while lfirst < len(left):
        arr[merge] = left[lfirst]
        lfirst+= 1
        merge += 1
        compar += 1
    while rfirst < len(right):
        arr[merge] = right[rfirst]
        rfirst += 1
        merge += 1
        compar += 1
    return(len(arr),call,compar)
size = 20 
high = 2000
array = list(np.random.randint(1, high + 1, size))
print(mergesort_helper(array))
```

Output: 20,39,20
Expected output: (20,39,68)

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: from your recursive call you only use the value of "call", you also need to use the other like this: `_,c,m=mergesort_helper(array)` and then `call += c` and `compar += m`

Answer (score 0):

Tell your subroutine that `call` and `compar` are globals, and initialize them in your main block:

```
import numpy as np
import random

def mergesort_helper(arr):
    global call
    global compar
    
    call += 1 
    if len(arr) <= 1:
        compar += 1
        return arr, call, compar
    if len(arr) > 1:
        compar += 1
        # Get middle of array
        mid = len(arr) // 2
        # Getting left side
        left = arr[:mid]
        #Getting right side
        right = arr[mid:]
        # Sorting the first half
        call += 1
        mergesort_helper(left)
        # Sorting the second half
        call += 1
        mergesort_helper(right)
        lfirst= 0
        rfirst = 0
        merge = 0
    while lfirst< len(left) and rfirst < len(right):
        # 3 comparisons here - two above and one below
        compar += 3
        if left[lfirst] < right[rfirst]:
            arr[merge] = left[lfirst]
            merge += 1
            lfirst+= 1
            
        else:
            arr[merge] = right[rfirst]
            rfirst += 1
            merge += 1
    # Checking if any element was left
    while lfirst < len(left):
        arr[merge] = left[lfirst]
        lfirst+= 1
        merge += 1
        compar += 1
    while rfirst < len(right):
        arr[merge] = right[rfirst]
        rfirst += 1
        merge += 1
        compar += 1
    return(len(arr),call,compar)

call = 0
compar = 0
size = 20 
high = 2000
array = list(np.random.randint(1, high + 1, size))

print("call=", call)
print("compar=", compar)
print(array)
print(mergesort_helper(array))
```

It looked to me like you missed a couple of places where `compar` should have been incremented, so I added them. I also changed the way that `call` was incremented.

This prints

```
call= 0                                                                                                                                                                            
compar= 0                                                                                                                                                                          
[47, 496, 1387, 644, 181, 1051, 966, 1431, 679, 1259, 1359, 912, 466, 1430, 731, 273, 55, 597, 1966, 346]                                                                          
(20, 77, 255)
```

which is probably not what you had in mind, but perhaps it gives you a way forward.

[See this OnlineGDB](https://onlinegdb.com/BkERQGTSO)